# How to define the message loop when using SetWinEventHook()?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm trying to listen to events in a third-party app window, in which I don't own the source.

I don't understand this part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) that says:

> The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events.

How do I 'define' this message loop?

In my hook code, it never reaches the `switch`:

```cpp
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
    DWORD event,
    HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject,
    LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread,
    DWORD dwmsEventTime
)
{   
    switch (event) {
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART:
            ...
            break;
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND:
            ...
            break;
    }
}

HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook;

int EventHook() {

    hWinEventHook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART,         // eventMin
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND,           // eventMax
        NULL,                               // hmodWinEventProc
        WinEventProc,                       // pfnWinEventProc
        4834,                               // idProcess
        0,                                  // idThread
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); //dwFlags

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::thread t1(EventHook);
    ...
}
```

I modified the code as suggested in comments, but now my program crashes;

It crashes when it gets to the line:

`while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))`

[image: crash]

Comment: "Message loop" is a shorthand for calling `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` repeatedly in a timely manner. The `while` loop in your example is in fact a message loop. To the extent there is a problem, it lies elsewhere. Have you checked whether `SetWinEventHook` call succeeded? Is `4834` the valid ID of some process? Have you minimized or restored some window belonging to that process?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you mean if `hWinEventHook` is returning a value? It does.

Comment: You have a message loop, but it is not good enough when you use std::async.  The requirement is that the message loop is running on the same thread that set the hook. 
Easy fix, you just don't need it to be async at all.

Comment: And you probably also need to compile for Windows instead of a console so that the main thread is a UI thread and the code should probably be run from the main thread or at least a STA thread. I think that hooks are somewhat hard to understand and get right and if not done properly might greatly affect the stability of the system. Best to avoid them unless you have no other choice and are willing to do a lot of reading...

Answer (score 1):

The message loop needs to be in main, in your case after the call to SetWinEventHook. And since you don't otherwise have a way for your program to exit you'll probably want to create a dialog with an exit button, and in the handler for that buttons BN_CLICKED use a call to MessageBox to confirm that the user wants to exit and if so do a PostQuitMessage). The confirmation is because it would be too easy to exit otherwise.

Comment: I modified the post, added a debug information, i dont understand what you mean need to be on `main`, my doubt is how to launch it on a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0):

The message loop you have shown is perfectly fine (after moving it into `EventHook()`).

The "crash" is not really a crash. It is simply the program terminating itself abruptly because the thread is still running when the `std::thread` object is destroyed, as you have not called `join()` or `detach()` on it before it went out of scope when `_tmain()` exited.

Per [`std::thread::~thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread):

> Destroys the thread object.
>
> **If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), [`std::terminate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called.**
>
> Notes
>
> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to destroy) after
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - [`join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) has been called
> - [`detach()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) has been called

So, simpy call `t1.join()` before `_tmain()` exits:

```cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::thread t1(EventHook);
    ... 
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to avoid the thread from being destroyed? I tried to define `t1` as a global variable, and now i got this error: `call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type`

Comment: I need to execute more code after calling the `EventHook()` this is why im asking for how to run it on a secondary thread.

Comment: @LeandroBoinha nothing in your question or previous comments say you want to run other code while the hook is running. If you need the thread, then just call `join()` on it before exiting.

Comment: I dont need the thread, what im trying to achieve is let the EventHook() running on a thread and run the rest of my code in another thread at same time. If i call join then it will stuck in the message loop of the EventHook()

Comment: @LeandroBoinha "*I dont need the thread*" - you are contradicting yourself. "*If i call join then it will stuck in the message loop of the EventHook()*" - no, it won't. `join()` will block the thread that calls it, ie the thread that `_tmain()` is running in. `EventHook()`, and its message loop, will continue to run unblocked in its own thread.